# Impala - First date of Month from string date

Tags: hadoop, hive, hiveql, impala

I have column data_as_of_daily_date (Data type String) in my source table (staging) and I need to find out First date of Month based on source table column in Impala and load it into target table having column FIRST_DAY_OF_MONTH (String type).

Source table:

```
+--------------------+
data_as_of_daily_date
+--------------------+
+20181217            +
+20181115            +
```

I am running below query:

```
SELECT 
      DATE_ADD(FROM_UNIXTIME(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(DATA_AS_OF_DAILY_DATE, 'yyyyMMdd')), 1 - DAY(FROM_UNIXTIME(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(DATA_AS_OF_DAILY_DATE, 'yyyyMMdd')))) AS FIRST_DAY_OF_MONTH
FROM TABLE;
```

Output:

```
+--------------------+
AS FIRST_DAY_OF_MONTH
+--------------------+
+2018-12-01 00:00:00 +
+2018-11-01 00:00:00 +
```

Expected Output:

```
+--------------------+
AS FIRST_DAY_OF_MONTH
+--------------------+
+20181201            +
+20181101            +
```

Answer (score 1):

No need to use from_unixtime,unix_timestamp unless you are changing the format.

```
select DATE_SUB(data_as_of_daily_date,DAY(data_as_of_daily_date) - 1) 
from table;
```

Comment: This query is returning NULL values, is it because data_as_of_daily_date column is of String type in Staging layer.

Comment: @ASaraf DATE_SUB( string date, int days )

Comment: Below is my query to test this and It is returning NULL as output

select DATE_SUB(DATA_AS_OF_DAILY_DATE,DAY(DATA_AS_OF_DAILY_DATE) - 1), DATA_AS_OF_DAILY_DATE  from
table_name
WHERE DATA_AS_OF_DAILY_DATE = '20181217';

Comment: What does select DATA_AS_OF_DAILY_DATE from table_name WHERE DATA_AS_OF_DAILY_DATE = '20181217' get you?

Comment: select DATE_SUB(DATA_AS_OF_DAILY_DATE,DAY(DATA_AS_OF_DAILY_DATE) - 1) as firstday, DATA_AS_OF_DAILY_DATE 
from table_name
WHERE DATA_AS_OF_DAILY_DATE = '20181217';

1 NULL 20181217 
2 NULL 20181217 
3 NULL 20181217